# Show processes running on remote computer using WMI

Tags: c#, wmi, remote-server, wmi-service

I'm using WMI in order to run commands on a remote machine.
For now, and I know it's as it should be, the process which is being run is not shown on the screen of the remote, I can only see it running when I open the task manager.

Like I said, I know it's ok.

My question is: Is there any way to overcome this issue and force the remote to show the executed process? (e.g. see calc's gui when I open it, or show notepad or cmd etc.).

Comment: Hi Idanis, you might be better off asking this on stackoverflow's sister site serverfault.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible using WMI. Three possible workarounds:

- psexec (option -i)
- scheduled tasks (you use schtasks /create)
- in older systems: at /interactive

Answer (score 0):

Try using WQL ,wmi query language and use Win32_Process .it shows same processes as in task manager. I did in C++ (though the code gets bit difficult).

(P.S. if u just want to run command only ,then this is not for u)